# Web Servlet Configuration

Tags: java, servlets

I have a question about the `<init-param>` element in my `web.xml` file. Can anybody explain me what I need to type in the parameters? Also, what do these parameters mean?

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name></param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: These are init parameters for a servlet. We can't tell you what you need to fill in there, it depends on what the specific servlet you are using needs.

Comment: That's just regular servlet parameterization, I believe. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/progservlet.html#wp159396

Comment: So what are the logic behind the using of this parameters in web xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the parameters that you can pass to servlet, and the init parameters of a servlet can only be accessed by that servlet.

```
   <init-param>
     <param-name>paramName</param-name>
     <param-value>value</param-value>
   </init-param>
```

That's how you can read the init parameters

```
String initParam = servletConfig.getInitParameter("paramName");
```

Comment: So what are the logic behind the using of this parameters in web xml ?

Comment: Well, you can use it for configuring your servlet. For example, if you use jawr, this parameters is used for configuring JawrServlet.

Comment: E.g. setting configLocation param
<init-param>
    <param-name>configLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/jawr.properties</param-value>
</init-param>

Comment: @Maks.Burkov These initialization parameters are one way to feed information needed by your servlet. Used for info you do not want to hard-code into your Servlet, items that you want to configure outside of your programming, items that may need to change over time but you don't want to bother to recompile your app to account for. Examples: The IP address or domain name of an email server for the servlet to use in sending out email notices, the name of a database server and the username and password to be used in connecting to that database, the time of day to generate the daily sales report.